# create a react input form with validation

Tags: reactjs

I am working on react input form but the problem is don't know how to validate, also not getting value on onChange, please have a look at my code.

I have created an array which value I need to update using the input form

```
useEffect(() => {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < Number(localStorage?.getItem("users")); i++) {
      arr.push({
        username: localStorage.getItem("userName"),
        user_email: localStorage.getItem("userEmail"),
        password: "",
        button: "",
        designation: "",
        country: "",
        city: "", 
        company_name: "",
      });
    }
    setUserRemaining(arr);
  }, []);
```

then i have input form , which i want with validation

```
{userRemaining.map((element, index) => {
                  return (
                    <div className="block2">
                      <input type="text" name="username" value='' onChange={(event) =>  handleChange(event, index)}/>
                      
                      <div className="add" onClick={() => addUser(element, index)}>
                        <span>
                          <img src={img1} />
                        </span>
                        Add
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  );
                })}
```

at last, here is my handleChange method I've tried.

```
const handleChange = (event, index) => {
    const updatedUser = userRemaining.map((users, index1) => {
      if (index1 == index) {
        return {
          ...users,
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        };
      } else {
        return users;
      }
```

for more details, I am providing a [link to the file too.](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-gauss-pq2wr?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I pretty recommend you use react hooks form
https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Applyvalidation
Its pretty easy input validations using this library
Here an small example

```js
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
   
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input {...register("firstName", { required: true, maxLength: 20 })} />
      <input {...register("lastName", { pattern: /^[A-Za-z]+$/i })} />
      <input type="number" {...register("age", { min: 18, max: 99 })} />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: tried but not working in my case, can you please check the link i have given.

Comment: ok this is working just want to add errors also to get validation.

Answer (score 0):

As Daher said, react hooks form is a great way to validate your inputs.

You can find all the ways you can validate them at https://www.operationdev.com/blog/a-complete-guide-to-react-form-validation/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32965032)

Answer (score 0):

React hooks form is a great way to validate your forms but if you need something richer and easier to use, check out this NPM package.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/octavalidate-reactjs

Octavalidate helps me to validate my forms in react seamlessly.